# ASP.NET Core MVC virtual path generation incorrect when including an Id within an Area

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-routing, asp.net-core-routing

I'm working in an ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC app and I'm trying to build a URL using the routing information. Everything works just fine as long as I stick with Area, Controller, and Action. As soon as I try to use Id, the path comes back incorrect

When I include everything except the id I get what I would expect

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Users" asp-action="Detail">User detail</a>
```

or from inside the UsersController

```
Url.Action("Detail")
```

produces

```
http://localhost:55556/Admin/Users/Detail
```

When I include the id

```
<a asp-area="Admin" asp-controller="Users" asp-action="Detail" asp-route-id="1">User detail</a>
```

or

```
Url.Action("Detail", new { id = 1 })
```

I get only

```
http://localhost:55556/1
```

This is what my routes look like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "areas",
    template: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "default",
    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
);
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

**Update**

It seems to have to do with the Area. When I leave the area out it produces what I would expect

```
Url.Action("Detail", "Users", new { id = 1 })
```

produces

```
/Users/Detail/1
```

Even though that doesn't actually exist. Though when I add the area

```
Url.Action("Detail", "Users", new { id = 1, area = "Admin" })
```

I get

```
/1
```

Has anyone else had trouble with Area routing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I had an incorrect `[HttpGet]` attribute on the action.

I had

```
[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public ActionResult Detail(int id)
{
    var user = _userRepository.GetUserById(id);
    var model = Mapper.Map<User, UserDetailModel>(user);

    return View(model);
}
```

Not realizing that the route I set into the attribute overwrote the default in full, and didn't just apply to the argument

I removed the the `("{id:int}")` and everything worked great